# User.IsInRole() always returning false

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have added some roles to AspNetroles tables, and I assigned those roles to user , But when i login with user Id and password which has roles assigned, condition always gets false.

I have added some roles to AspNetroles tables, and I assigned those roles to user , But when i login with user Id and password which has roles assigned, condition always gets false.

I debugged my code but user.Isinrole always gets false.

Please can anyone help me?

[Tables with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkWRs.png)

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" }) 
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                @User.Identity.AuthenticationType
                @{
                    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        if (User.IsInRole("administrator"))
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Admin")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Admin")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Doctor", "Doctor", "Admin")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Receptionist", "Receptionist", "Admin")</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Admin")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Admin")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Doctor", "Doctor", "Admin")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Receptionist", "Receptionist", "Admin")</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        if (User.IsInRole("Doctor"))
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Doctor")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", "Doctor")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Appointment", "Appointment", "Doctor")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage", "Manage", "Doctor")</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        if (User.IsInRole("Patient"))
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Patient")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Schedule", "Patient")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Appointments", "Appointments", "Patient")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payment", "Payment", "Patient")</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        if (User.IsInRole("Receptionist"))
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Patient")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Appointments", "Schedule", "Patient")</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        if (User.IsInRole(""))
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    }

                }
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
```

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignIn(SignInview Sv)
    {

        var Auser = _context.AspNetUsers.Where(m => m.UserName == Sv.Username).SingleOrDefault();
        if(Auser!=null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Sv.Username, true);
            Session["User"] = Auser.UserName;
            Session["UserId"] = Auser.Id;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username or password is wrong");
            return View(Sv);
        }

    }
```

Comment: User.IsInRole doesn't check the database. It checks the claims of the user: User.Claims. So you'll need to make sure the roles are added as claims.

Comment: How do I make sure the roles are added as claims??

Comment: You should use the UserManager instead of calling the AspNet tables directly. See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613290(v%3dvs.108)